# java manytomany mapping not creating

Tags: java, many-to-many, persistence

I created two simple entities for trying out the java persistence manytomany mapping. But whatever I try, the jointable won't be populated with a mapping and remains empty.

UserClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Order.class ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_orders",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "orderUsers")
    private Set<Order> userOrders = new HashSet<>();
}
```

OrderClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userOrders", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "userOrders")
    private Set<User> orderUsers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I added Getter/Setter/Constructor via Lombok.
Create and save an user. Create an order, add the user and save it. But still the jointable remains empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: The problem might be that the user is the owner of the relation and if you didn't also add the order to `userOrders` you won't see any changes. Btw, can an order really have many associated users?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that both can have multiple users/orders.
Well...but if I need to add the order also to userOrders, don't I get in a loop?

Comment: Wow....this already works!
getUser; user.addOrder; createOrder; order.addUser; saveUser;
So the missing part was to add the order to the user before adding it to the order.
But this seems a little bit confusing to me...

Comment: You need to read up on what "owning side" means. It's basically the user and not the order in your case ("mappedBy" is an indicator of not being the owning side).